# Stack Exchange android application crashes too often

Tags: bug, android-app

This app crashes too often. I open the app, scroll down to see the feeds and it crashes. Next time I open it, it goes smoothly. Then I click on a question, scroll down and the app crashes. I do the same, it goes smoothly. I now in the same run, open my profile, click on a answer I posted and the app crashed! I have knowledge of app development but still can't figure out what the problem is. I think when the answer consists of code or blockquote, the app crashes. I'm using android 4.1.1 having 512 MB RAM, MDPI resolution, stock ROM, Stack Exchange app v1.0.43

Also when the app crashes, it does not show- Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has crashed. It just closes so I can't even report it! When I long press the home button, it doesn't show the previous screen that was open. It shows transparent black screen.

**Update:** Saved it using catlog( I have a rooted device):- [log.text on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgam20rlo4mt5rn/Stackexchange%20log.txt) Tell me if this of any use. Started recording with log filter set to "com.stackexchange" and log level "verbose(default)" and started using the application until it crashed. Did not restart the application then. Stopped the log recording. (If you read the log, try it from the bottom to up, as I used the application while trying to get to crash.) 
Today once more this application crashed and I have logged it. Please look into [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2okk8hefuuswbc/Stacke%20log%20crash.txt).

Comment: Sounds like running out of memory. However frustrating, without identifying something specific this isn't likely to be an actionable bug report.

Comment: @AD7six How can I log the errors into a file like a logcat report? Please suggest appropriate action

Comment: This happens to me too, but I don't see how it could possibly be a memory issue as I rarely have many apps or programs running

Comment: @dhaval.s Logcat got a little more complicated in Android 4.1 because logcat had restrictions put on it to prevent apps from reading the log easily. If you're familiar with app dev, you can just connect your phone to a computer, enable USB debugging and then use `adb logcat` to get the output.

Comment: @StevenV Will the adb logcat give me the same log as if I was developing it? I mean when I develop an app, and an error occurs, it will also give me the exact line at which the error has occurred.

Comment: @AD7six  I edited my question and uploaded the log. Kindly look into it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216102/200868

Comment: @AsheeshR Haha. LOL :P But in some other post I read that about 70% of these have been fixed. But still after the 18 Jun update (1.0.42) it's quite buggy.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Since you have you been very kind and responsive on Meta site, please look into this and reply with an answer.

Comment: @dhaval.s I'm not in a position to say, having provided a log at least now there's a chance for someone to point out something specific e.g. this sounds useful `WIN DEATH: Window{42e46d28 com.stackexchange.marvin/com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.BaseActivity paused=false}`. Please stop attempting to ping people for your bug report - it's the weekend (even it it wasn't - it's pretty rude), and if I were on the SE team I'd react to such behavior by prioritizing to work on other tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you so much for the detailed report! From the looks of the logcat files it seems as if the app is being killed since the `WebView` rendering we're using for questions and answers is too intensive on your device. I don't quite know where to start on trying to fix that since dealing with `WebView`s is kind of a mess (Pre android 4.4 they are powered by WebKit, post android 4.4 they're powered by Chromium), but I'm going to investigate this with my lower end device (Android 4.0.4 on a device with 512 MB RAM) and see what I can do. I'll update this post as work on this progresses.