# What is the Stack Exchange API used for?

Tags: discussion, api

This may sound stupid to those of you who happen to know, but I just can't figure out any practical use case where one would need to use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Examples: http://stackapps.com/

Comment: I personally use it to make [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8).  There's only a small subset of features of the app that aren't available in the API.

Answer (score 3):

From the top of my head...

1. Building [your own apps for smartphones](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app), used to interact with Stack Exchange.
2. [Poll new questions searching for spam and help Stack Exchange hunt it down](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector).

And of course, Stack Exchange itself use the API as the backend for both [android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215992/stack-exchange-android-app-in-beta) and [iOS app](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/).

Answer (score 3):

On [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is it commonly used to create leaderboards. There might be other sites around the network where it has similar uses.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is the [User Score by Tag](http://output.jsbin.com/azeqec/9?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=1221571) tool, which someone created when the daily script that updates tag scores didn't run for many days in a row.

Comment: Awesome, never saw that tool! Just don't run it over Jon Skeet, it will run out of quota instantly... :)