# Stack Overflow chat application for mobiles

Tags: support, chat

I am using an Android smartphone. I wanted to know if there is a mobile application through which we can use chat?

Comment: There is an android app currently in development. I don't believe the current alpha release has chat but the final version may. You can see some details regarding the [in development app here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently, no, however you can access chat via the browser on your mobile device simply by browsing to https://chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: Dose it works properly??

Comment: Properly?  Yes.  It just 
doesn't have all the features of the desktop web edition