# Top Posts view - vote count cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

A picture is worth a thousand words. [My top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than/12135533#12135533) has four digits of votes. Besides, `009` is an invalid octal number.

Also, just noticed that the `performance` tag, at only 11 characters, is also cut off.

[image]

Comment: shedding a single 'e' could result in billions of bytes saved and great increases in performance. it is a great idea for that tag to be an example of its own topic. in fact in the spirit of that tag let's rename it to _pformanc_

Comment: @AlienArrays You realize that this is a bug report for the alpha version of this app right? And I'm simply reporting it, [as requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app)...

Comment: 10 downvotes seem doable :) anywho, nice bug report

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report! Both of these issues are fixed in version 0.1.90 coming out around midnight UTC.