# Why isn't there an official SO App for major platforms which simply browses to the SO site?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

I've read the proposed FAQ on [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use), but it still doesn't answer my question. I think SO has done a great job making the site work well on mobile devices and presumably tablets as well. I also know that users can create an icon on their Android desktop to call up the SO site and presumably on the other platforms.

But honestly, I hadn't figured out how to do that until today when I checked again and saw there was still no SO app available. Having an invoke-the-browser version app for major platforms seems like it would provide added visibility and credibility for SO and convenience for users. Is there something I'm not aware of that's preventing this from being done? Do the platforms have a policy against doing so? I'm assuming the work is not significant and would represent pretty much a one-time investment.

Comment: Why would you want an app that just links to the website? What if every website did that?

Comment: See question for why I think it's a good idea. As for the impact of every site doing that (or at least every site in the category of SO in terms of user base), I think it would be helpful. Apps are already so numerous that you find them through search and stackoverflow already appears in the app search cache for Android and presumably the others. It would simply give users a way to treat their access to SO like they do most of the other major services they rely on from their mobile device (i.e. via the platform app store and management software).

Comment: No one is going to look for a Stack Overflow app for iOS or Android or Windows Phone that doesn't know what the site is about, and then if they just want a link, they can easily create their own be it on the desktop or the mobile browser favorites

Comment: First, we had applications. Then, we had web applications, which are applications that run inside applications. Now we have webview-based apps, which are applications that run inside applications that run inside applications. I hope I'll have retired before the next step, but I'm afraid it will come sooner than I think.

Comment: There is actually an android app which just opens SO in your browser.

Comment: @Amicable - And the name of it is ????

Comment: Well, [they are hiring developers to build mobile applications](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/34231/mobile-developer-stack-exchange-stack-exchange), if you feel strongly enough about it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin [Search the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=stack+overflow&c=apps).

Comment: @Amicable - That search returns a list of 111 apps for me, none of them named StackOverflow, none that I could find published by SE and the few that I checked are using the SE API, not just invoking the SO web page. What am I missing?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - ;-) I know you were being humorous, but a mobile app which invokes the browser doesn't result in the browser running "in the app" any more than command line execution of a GUI app results in the GUI app running "in the command line".  It's a transfer of execution, not execution within a framework (at least I'm assuming that's would could and would be done).

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Nothing, plenty of those apps do what I stated.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to present to you my truly magical new iOS application for viewing Stack Overflow:

[image]

[image]

It opens Stack Overflow directly in a web view, supports iPhone and iPad, and...that's pretty much it. It took me about 10 minutes to create, and the source code can be downloaded from here:

http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/StackOverflowViewer.zip

It currently lacks back, forward, or any other kind of buttons, but I imagine those could be made an in-app purchase.

Comment: :-) If you can get SE's ok to put it in the app store with that name and image, or better yet, get them to publish it so it appears as from them, I predict many downloads. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Make your own app in 3 easy steps:

- Go to SO
- Tap the action button

[image]

- Select "Add to Home Screen"

[image]

Voilà! An app that magically brings you to the SO home page.

[image]

Supports all iOS devices and OS versions.

Comment: I've not used iOS devices much and my Android phone only slightly more, so I checked the equivalent Android functionality. Sure enough, it's there. When I tried to use it, it failed with an error that my home page was full, but succeeded of course when I made some space. Unlike above, it showed as the Google bookmark icon with a teeny SO logo inside of it that was hardly recognizable. There's a message for me here that I need to "get out more" wrt mobile devices. ;-) Given how easy shortcut creation really is, I now see the value proposition is much less. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing preventing creation of an app that performs as described, as at least one (StackMob) and reportedly many (per @Amicable) already exist, albeit not published by SE.

As for why none of these 3rd party apps carry the StackOverflow name, that's presumably due to trademark issues.

As for why SE hasn't produced such an app with the StackOverflow name, the answer isn't known. They are hiring mobile app developers, but obviously not to create a go-to-the-web app. ;-)

Given how easy it is create desktop shortcuts to web pages on the mobile platforms, there really is marginal utility for most users of a trivial app like this. The value proposition for an SE-published app of this sort would be:
* Cause users not familiar with the quality of SO's mobile implementation to try it out assuming they're only interested in an "app" and look in the app store
* Provide more SO visibility via the app store
* Allow SE to easily migrate users to a hybrid implementation at some point in the future
* Easily support the standard SO icon on the desktop for platforms that show a bookmark