# Teams support for apps?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-app, stack-overflow-for-teams

Teams is a (pretty neat) product that you are selling. The Stack Exchange app can't see any inbox notifications for Teams or access them, which is understandable... but I recently installed the Stack Overflow app (on iOS) and it doesn't understand teams either!

Is there a plan to support Teams on the apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [bad news](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154798/295232) is that

> The official mobile apps are no longer under active development

The good news is that Stack Overflow for Teams is supported by [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) (be it in read-only mode), so it's possible for developers to make an app which accesses Teams data.