# Android app alternatives

Tags: discussion, android-app

It looks like the official stack exchange app has been abandoned, so I abandoned it as well. It lacks a ton of features,and is kinda crappy. However, I really miss push notifications and not having to navigate to each of the 7 sites I'm active in.

So my question is if there is an alternative to it (either unofficial or official)

I looked at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use) but all the apps listed there are not found in the play store. All the apps listed at the question no longer are in the play store (item not found at link)

Comment: [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use) contains a list of alternative apps.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog a list of defunct, non-existent apps . So I guess I'm left as checking several sites manually. No need for ease or lack of irritation for me.